# Can anyone help me know if my app can get it into the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

So, 
I've been asked to make an iOS app that acts as the front sales to another system.

As this is an app that will only work for the salesman, can it go in the app store? I know I can deploy using "Distributing Enterprise Apps" but this will be my last resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only for a few people then you can add their device UDIDs to your developer account and just send them the IPA file or do the online ad-hoc thing.

Look at the section titled "How Do I Send the Beta Testers an Ad-Hoc Build?" on here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1669/how-to-host-a-beta-test-for-your-ios-app for some help. I know it says for beta testing but it still works.

EDIT: Given that you will have many users, the enterprise program is your only choice shy of doing it as a web app so as to bypass the App Store all together. Apple won't allow enterprise apps (e.g. a POS app custom written for a single client) onto the store afaik. If it's a generic app that will be used by many companies then it should be allowed assuming that all other criteria are met.

Try it and if they reject it then that's your answer.

Comment: That won't work either, it will be used by many people, and manage the UDIDs won't work.

Comment: It's enterprise apps then. Simple as that.